# Open Street Map (pyproj). How to solve syntax issue?

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj, contextily

Using pyproj for visualizing open street map and getting the following error:

```
> AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs.py:77:
> FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated.
> '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method.   return
> _prepare_from_string(" ".join(pjargs))
```

The program runs but spits out a map that is blank.

There's not much I could find on google. What is this and how to fix it?

See code snippet below:

```
##Create map
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
new_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(new_df, crs=crs)

#Contextly
new_df = new_df.to_crs(epsg=3857) 

##Plot
variable = 'All' #set a variable that will call column
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(50, 50)) #create figure and axes for Matplotlib
ox = new_df.plot(column=variable, cmap='viridis', linewidth=0.3, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8',alpha=0.5,scheme='equal_interval',k=10,legend=True,legend_kwds={'loc': 'lower left'})

##ADD BASEMAP
ctx.add_basemap(ox,zoom=15)

#Remove the axis
ox.set_axis_off()

##Save Map
plt.savefig('Latest_Map.png')
##Show Map
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: that's just a warning, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: maybe include some of your code, e.g. what lat/lon you are looking at.

Comment: _What is this and how to fix it?_ That's difficult to answer with this little information to work with.

Comment: Please see code above.

Comment: The warning is coming from the internals of GeoPandas. This will be solved with the next version of GeoPandas, but for now nothing you can do about it, so it is safe to ignore it in this case.

Comment: @joris Any idea why the map comes out blank? I've attached the picture so you can see what I mean. I see the legend and the "openstreetmap" writting at the bottom but nothing else.

Comment: Seems like this could be an issue with one of the dependencies (pyproj)

Comment: This is not your full code isn't it? What values did you assign for to the `new_df`? Can you add your full code

Comment: the warning comes from pyproj, see here: http://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html

Comment: @adatzer How would you apply this to the project? Would it be possible to show how you would modify code?

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the syntax issue, the warning comes from pyproj, when you reproject. Geopandas has changed its docs to reflect that (see https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/1101/files#diff-dc9328ce726fd6e58f466f7001f7a50e and https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/31b264fabb88367a63823da107c764ccec4d3e8f/doc/source/projections.rst) and advices:

- setting by hand

> my_geoseries.crs = "EPSG:4326"

- reprojecting

> world = world.to_crs("EPSG:3395") # world.to_crs(epsg=3395) would also work

Note: the `world.to_crs(epsg=3395)` will indeed work, but it will still issue a warning (because of the `from_espg` function of `fiona.crs` that gets called internally and still uses the `{'init':...`). If you want no warnings:

```
new_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(new_df)
new_df.crs = "EPSG:4326"    # set it by hand

new_df = new_df.to_crs("EPSG:3857")
```

However, this should not be, and probably is not the reason why your map is blank. Without knowing your actual `new_df` is hard to tell, but trying your code with a df from geopandas datasets(`naturalearth_lowres`) it seems to work fine.. having had some issues with the zoom, i'd suggest that you call the `ctx.add_basemap` *without* the `zoom=15` argument (the default is `zoom="auto"`) and see.

Comment: Changed the syntax to `new_df.crs = "EPSG:4326"` in my code, but still get the FutureWarning. The `from_espg` function of `fiona.crs` is indeed changing the crs string to `{'init': ...}` format. It seems like there won't be any changes in the new version of Fiona (2.0 dev) regarding the `from_espg` behavior. Is there any way to silence this warning or should we wait for Geopandas update?

Comment: the warning comes when you re-project, not from just setting the crs, so check also how you apply the `to_crs` method later on. Fiona's `from_epsg` will get called if you apply it like this: `new_df.to_crs(epsg=xxxx)` (because you provide the epsg argument). So, you need *both* to set the `.crs` like you do *and* also apply the `.to_crs` like in the answer above. If i do *both* like this i get no warning (pyproj v2.4.2, geopandas v0.6.2). Concerning updates and future versions, i am not involved, so i don't know what to expect.

Comment: thanks for clarification. in my case `new_df.to_crs(epsg=xxxx)` is being internally called by `folium.GeoJson()` with only epsg passed and no crs.